# Setting a TextView to visible from invisible based on an if statement

Tags: java, android

I have several strings of text on a screen that are set to invisible when the application starts.  When a button is clicked on another screen, I want a specific string to become visible.  Ultimately I want to have a few strings, of the several, become visible as a result of clicking this button.

```
    public void buttona0Click(View view){
    setContentView(R.layout.report_screen);
    buttonClicked2 = 1;
    if(buttonClicked1==1){
        setVisibility(R.id.textView2.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

I am primarily looking for guidance on this line

```
    setVisibility(R.id.textView2.VISIBLE);
```

I am new to programming in general, so I don't know if what I've said makes sense to most of you. Is `.setText` an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate your `TextView` first. So the easiest way to begin is to declare them before `onCreate()` and outside of any other method so they are member variables

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    TextView tv1, tv2, etc...;

    public void onCreate(...)
    {
        super.onCreate(...);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        ...
     }
```

Then in your `onClick()` change the `Visibility` which takes an `int` value

```
 public void buttona0Click(View view){
     buttonClicked2 = 1;
     if(buttonClicked1==1){
         tv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

**Note:** please don't include the "..." above in your code. That is just omitted code that I assume you know how to handle already. Also, I took out `setContentView()` from the `onClick()` method because typically this should only be done once in `onCreate()`.

I'm not sure about the logic inside there because I don't know what the `buttonClicked1` variables are for but that is how to do the `Visibility`.

[setVisibility() Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29)

> Is .setText an alternative?

This will simply set the text so if you have it already set in your xml then you don't need to...you can just change the `Visibility` as you are trying to do. If you haven't set it then you will need to with something like

```
tv1.setText("Hello World");  // input your own String or String resource
```

Answer (score 1):

Write your own algo:

1. Use one boolean
2. view VISIBLE and GONE based own above boolean variable

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call `setVisibility(View.GONE)` for all your TextViews in `onCreate()` after `setContentView()`. Then in your if clause set the visibility of selected textview to View.VISIBLE - `textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`

Answer (score 0):

First `findViewById` of the `TextView` and in `onClick` function of your button set visibility of that textView as `VISIBLE`

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


 public void buttona0Click(View view){
     buttonClicked2 = 1;
    if(buttonClicked1==1){
        textView.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
        }
}
```